# ajax data variables don't update

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, postgresql

Hi there sorry for the basic problem (I'm very new at this), but I was making an insert data for a database through a map API using jquery and ajax. The thing is in the $POST function the latitude and longitude doesn't update in the submit(or post) "event".

I know the variable `coordenada` updates when I'm doing `dblclicks` alongside the map. I'm sure about that because `mostrarModal()` is a function where it displays a modal and that modal has an input where I can see how it updates.

Finally, as I mentioned, the coordenada always updates but when I'm doing the "instert" in the post method, when I review the database,  it saves the first lat-lng instead the updated lat-lng.

here is the js code, I also put the php code but I don't think that is the problem.

PS. the commented lines in coordenada explains how that variable works and `salirModal` is like mostrarModal, it hides and reset the `$(#forma-recurso)`.
Thx a lot for your time. Greetings from chile.

JS code

```
map.on('dblclick',function(e){
$('.btn-salir').click(salirModal); 
var coordenada= mostrarModal(e);
    /*var latitud= e.latlng.lat;
    var longitud= e.latlng.lng;
    var coordenada={latitud:latitud, longitud:longitud};*/
alert(coordenada.latitud+''+coordenada.longitud);

    $('#forma-recurso').submit(coordenada,function(e){

    var nombre_recurso=$('.nombre-recurso').val();
    var direccion_recurso=$('.direccion-recurso').val();
    var descripcion_recurso=$('.descripcion-recurso').val();
    var tipo_pto_interes=$('.tipo-pto-interes').val();

    $.post('ingreso_re.php',{nombre_recurso:nombre_recurso,
                        direccion_recurso:direccion_recurso,
                       descripcion_recurso:descripcion_recurso,
                       tipo_pto_interes:tipo_pto_interes,
                       latitud:coordenada.latitud,
                       longitud:coordenada.longitud },function (data){

        if(data[0].answer==1){
    alert('el recurso ya existe');


    }else if(data[0].answer!=1){
    salirModal();
    alert('el recurso se almacenó');


    }
 },"json");   

e.preventDefault();
});


});
```

And the PHP code

```
<?php

   $nombre_recurso = $_POST['nombre_recurso'];
    $direccion_recurso = $_POST['direccion_recurso'];
    $descripcion_recurso=$_POST['descripcion_recurso'];
    $tipo_pto_interes=$_POST['tipo_pto_interes'];
    $latitud=$_POST['latitud'];
    $longitud=$_POST['longitud'];

$dbconn3 = pg_connect("host= localhost port=5432 dbname=EmergenciesResponse user=postgres password=asdf");
//$consultaUsuario=pg_query("select id_usuario, clave_usuario from usuarios where id_usuario='$id_usuario' and clave_usuario='$clave_usuario'");
$consultaIdRecurso=pg_query("select static_resource_name from static_resource where static_resource_name='".$nombre_recurso."'");
$consultaImagen=pg_query("select i.imagen from img_pto_interes i where i.tipo_pto_interes='$tipo_pto_interes'");


if(pg_num_rows($consultaIdRecurso)==1)
{   
     $answer[]=array(
        'answer'=>1
                );
    echo json_encode($answer);


}else
    { 
    $insertarRecurso=pg_query("INSERT INTO static_resource VALUES('".$nombre_recurso."',
    '".$direccion_recurso."',
    '".$descripcion_recurso."',
    '".$latitud."',
    '".$longitud."',
    '".$tipo_pto_interes."')");

  while($registro=pg_fetch_array($consultaImagen)){



    $answer[]=array(
        'nombre_recurso'=>$nombre_recurso,
        'latitud'=>$latitud,
        'longitud'=>$longitud,
        'imagen_recurso'=>$registro['imagen'],
        'answer'=>0
                );

    echo json_encode($answer);
  }
}

pg_close($dbconn3);

?>
```

Comment: All of your bindings are set within the other click events? Is this the behavior you are wanting? To bind the clilck event only when, not before, the double click occurs, and so on? This will cause your data to not be handled as expected if not.

Comment: Just check if the values are getting posted in console.

Comment: @Casey Im not understanding well about the binding, but the submit and map event come from different clicks. first I click the map, then fill a little form and finally click submit. What i want to do is pass the parameter "coordenada" into the submit event but it doesnt update